# How to execute a code only for the blog post page on my functions.php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to execute a simple code via my functions.php file (child theme) on my wordpress website.

The code should return "yes blog" when I open the blog post page, and return "no blog" for any other page. But it only returns "no blog" whatever the page.
I tried different conditionnal tags :

- is_home()
- is_front_page() && is_home()
- !is_front_page() && is_home()
- is_page_template()
- is_page('')

It always returns "no blog"
I have a default front page and a default blog page on my website.

Here is my code:

```html
   if(is_home()){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("yes blog")';
    echo '</script>';
        } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("no blog")';
        echo '</script>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the if condition with something like:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/blog")
```

Answer (score 0):

The "blog" page is a page and has an ID, so you can write something like:

```
if (is_page(345)) {
   // content/code for page whose ID is 345
} else {
  // content/code for pages whose ID is not 345
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if you're on the blog page by looking at the request URI or the page ID is a bad thing since it's hard coded.

You should use these conditions :

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```

Make sure you have registered a front page (for is_front_page() cond.) or a blog page (is_home() cond.) in your Wordpress permalinks options

This thread will maybe help : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107141/check-if-current-page-is-the-blog-page

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I did use the code exactly as it appears on the codex.wordpress documentation, but it remains throwing "no blog". It's driving me crazy as it seems to be so simple to use.

Comment: Can you tell me where your code is ? In a template ? In a functions.php hook ?
And sorry about that, but I told you to look in the "Permalink options" but the option to configure a static blog page is in the "Settings > Reading" options